# Git merge parallel feature branches

Tags: git, merge, branching-and-merging

i try to work with git like described in the [A succesfull git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). Today i started to work on "Feature A". While developing for it, it quickly became clear i need another "Feature B" to make my life easier. So "Feature A" depends on "Feature B". I therefore created a new branch for "Feature B" and implemented it. But how do i now proceed? Do i merge Feature B into Feature A? Do i merge Feature B into Development and "re-merge" development into Feature A? Or do i merge "Feature B" into "Feature A" and development?

Any ideas? Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you see the illustration of the mentioned gitBranching model you can notice that we always merge branch with the *direct ancestor* branch.
**E.g**: All feature branches created from the "develop" branch are merged with the "develop" branch and no other branch.

I guess you created the "feature B" branch from the "feature A" (i.e from "feature A": `git checkout -b "feature B"`). 
To follow the pattern you ought to merge it with "feature A" branch and no other branch, even develop branch.

Moreover "feature B" make sens only for "feature A" branch. Merging it with another branch **will hide** the reason behind its creation (that is, I created feature B because I needed it to implement feature A).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Thats the way i just did it myself now. And everything looks good. My biggest fear was to create some "double merge conflict" or something. But all went fine! :)

Answer (score 0):

If "Feature A" depends on "Feature B" then merging B into develop makes no sense, so you probably want to merge it to A first. If the changes from B were made **only** for new code from branch A, then you might consider skipping B and simply commiting them on A.